# Most Important Southeast Asian scholars

Tags: history

Who were the most important scholars from Malaysia and Indonesia in the history of Islam? What were their contributions?

Comment: See the list of Asia to find Indo/Malay Islamic scholar of this Wikipedia's article [List of contemporary Islamic scholars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_contemporary_Islamic_scholars)

Comment: @AbduRahman I mean historical scholars, not modern.

Comment: Both these countries were founded/gained independence in mid 1900 so there wouldn't be a historical scholar.

Comment: @AbduRahman They didn't have independence, but there were still millions of Muslims living in Southeast Asia, before the 20th century, and some of these must have been scholars.

Comment: Questions asking for a "most" whatever are usually attraction opinion-based answers and are therefore a bad fit for this site. The same applies for list-questions!